# Data doesn't reach till reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use in my react application redux saga. There i have a login form. With redux saga i try to handle the error when user login.
Bellow is my saga:

```js
function* postLoginUserReq(user) {
    const {name} = user.values.user;
    try {
        const data = yield call(() => {
            return fetch("url", {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: name,
                }),
            }).then(data => data.json()).then(response => {
                userErrorLogIn(response.error) //here i check if appears an error

            })
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Bellow is action creator:

```js
export const userErrorLogIn = (error) => {
    console.log(error)  //the error message appears here
    return {
        type: USER_ERROR_LOGIN,
        payload: error
    };
};
```

Bellow is reducer:

```js
 case USER_ERROR_LOGIN: {
            console.log(action.payload)  //here the error message does not appears (why?)
            return {
                ...state,
                userIsLoggedError:action.payload,
            }
        }
```

**Question**: What could be the issue that i don't get the error in reducer?

Comment: Can you show your whole reducer? Reducer is registered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .catch for that -

```
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => console.log("ok") )
    .catch(error => userErrorLogIn(error) );
```

https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/